# Making embedded PDF scrollable in iPad

Tags: html, ipad, pdf

I have a PDF embedded in HTML using the object tag. The embedded PDF is a big document and when viewed from my desktop the PDF is displayed properly with scrollbar in all the browsers including safari. However when I view the same html page in iPad the embedded PDF does not have a scrollbar. Is there any way in which we can show the scrollbar in iPad for an embedded PDF document.

The code used for embeding the PDF is

```
<object data="pdf.pdf" type="application/pdf" width="1000px" height="1200px" id="pdfDoc" name="pdfDoc"></object>
```

I tried with iframe too and even that does not work.

Comment: Scrollbars are not prominent in iOS, they are merely an indicator of how far you have scrolled through a content piece, not to signify that scrolling is possible.

Comment: @Albin : Did it worked in ipad with single finger scroll. With two finger scroll its working for me...Please find the link here 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186427/scrolling-with-single-finger-gesture-for-object-element-ipad-not-working

Answer (score 12):

This seems to work:

- make the object tag big enough to show the whole PDF, and
- contain it in a div with limited height and overflow:auto -- add -webkit-overflow-scrolling in iOS 5+ for good, native scrolling.

Here's the code I used:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>PDF frame scrolling test</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
      #container { overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; height: 500px; }
      object { width: 500px; height: 10000px }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <object id="obj" data="my.pdf" >object can't be rendered</object>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried this approach. But in iPad I can see only first page image. I am not able to scroll

Comment: @IfOnly: did u get any solution? Please share if u have fixed the issue. I am  facing the same :(

Comment: unfortunately no. Instead I provided a link to PDF and opened the PDF in separate view.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing, so here I share.

Issues I faced:

- Cropped content : [iframe on iOS (iPad) content cropping issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814256/iframe-on-ios-ipad-content-cropping-issue)
- Scrollbars not shown : [Making embedded PDF scrollable in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8237708/making-embedded-pdf-scrollable-in-ipad)
- Cannot make full width

Please try the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/aknMJ/2/embedded/result/

Used tricks:

1. Read the document width and scale the PDF frame according to that
2. "width:100%" does not work with iframes in iPad, so I needed to use CSS3 transformations
3. Wait until the PDF is completely loaded and then show&resize the PDF frame. Otherwise the content was cropped.

```js
$('#pdfFrame').hide();
var pdfFrame = document.getElementById('pdfFrame');
pdfFrame.contentWindow.location.replace(PDF_URL);
$('#pdfFrame').on('load', function () {
    $('#pdfFrame').show();
    var documentWidth = $(document).width()
    var scale = (documentWidth / width) * 0.95;
    $('#pdfFrame').css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + scale + ")");
});
```

Comment: i feel like i spent weeks with this issue and now i'm am so exhausted, but i find a solution for myself:

$('#pdf_iframe').css("-webkit-transform", "scale(" + 1.63 + ")");
$('#pdf_iframe').css("zoom", "0.63");

The combination of these two properties after the pdf is loaded dynamically succeed to fit the pdf documents width into ipad properly. if someone wants explanations, feel free to notify me.

Comment: about the scroll issue, sadly but the working solution is to make iframe's height fixed and this height has to be equal of the pdf's size.

Comment: about my first comment - you have to experimenting with the values to make it fit. the values in the example work only for my case, i think.

Comment: another approach is to use pdf.js but it's kind of tricky and it's hard to be implemented in a working project.

Comment: Hi @VladimirTrifonov , Thanks for ur comment. I am facing similar issue like u mentioned. I want to embedd PDF in iOS-8.4, Android4.4+ cordova apps also in its web app version. I have tried using Iframe , pdf loaded correctly but Iam facing scroll issue. Do u have any comments on It?

Answer (score 0):

On the iPad you can use two fingers to scroll embedded content - this works for divs with overflow:scroll

Comment: But still the scrollbars are invisible. Is there any way we can make the scrollbars visible in ipad?

Comment: @Matt Any idea for one finger scroll in ipad. With two its working. For reference here is my question 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186427/scrolling-with-single-finger-gesture-for-object-element-ipad-not-working

Answer (score 0):

PDF.js is working perfectly in our case.

You can check the full 1-line solution here: [Make embedded PDF scrollable in iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15854537/make-embedded-pdf-scrollable-in-ipad/32518877#32518877)

Good luck

Comment: PDF.js casues huge memory leaks on iOS, wouldn't recommend using it at all.

Comment: Do you have an alternative? That's the only working solution we have so far.

Comment: In iOS the <object> tag uses far less memory, although it takes more time and effort to have it working correctly (scroll and resizing).