# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined during get browser function

Tags: javascript

```
function get_browser() {
    var N = navigator.appName, ua = navigator.userAgent, tem;
    var M = ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
    if (M && (tem = ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) !== null)
              M[2] = tem[1];
    M = M ? [M[1], M[2]] : [N, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    return M[0];

}
```

***Its edited and no longer a Question ***

Comment: you can refer here.. if you want to know which browser your client is using.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489546/how-to-get-browsers-name-client-side

Comment: Why are you doing UA sniffing? Use Modernizr.

Comment: It fails because IE11 no longer has MSIE in the userAgent! TADA! It will break when anyone comes i with a modified useragent. It is a bad script.

Comment: Currently I am  not supporting IE .so thats why I am comfortable with this script .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't ever assign a value to `tem`, so `tem[1]` is essentially saying `undefined[1]`. Hence the error.

Change

```
if (M && (tem === ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) !== null)
```

to

```
if (M && (tem = ua.match(/version\/([\.\d]+)/i)) !== null)
```

That is, change the `===` comparison to an assignment.

**And then rethink why it is you "need" to know which browser the user has.**

Comment: i need to know because i want to run my application just latest version or currently i am not supporting mobile or IE.thats why i want to get browser or browser version