# Prevent JS from revealing IE browser by running conditional compilations

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, browser, activex

The JS code below can reveal if your browser is an IE.

```
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/!1;
```

Is there a way to prevent this behavior without disabling javascript?

Comment: Even if you could disable this behavior in particular, [there are other ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12489546/how-to-get-browsers-name-client-side) to detect this.

Comment: I am doing one step at a time :)

Comment: What's your end goal? As a long time web developer I can think of dozens and dozens of ways that a "web view" could reveal to me that it is Internet Explorer... And even more through code. I see this as a pretty hopeless quest.

Comment: @scunliffe End goal is a custom IE with total anonymity. Removing this kind of browser sniffing is important part of it.  Apart from using ua string, conditional compilations, documentMode, clientCaps and maybe a couple more methods there is no much more ways to detect it. Why would you call it hopless?

Comment: @Milos I consider it hopeless as each browser IE/Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Opera etc gives various hints as to which browser it actually is. I can run JavaScript that will tell me if a browser is IE7, IE8, IE9, IE10, IE11 etc.  One can even detect if it is IE11 on windows 8 running on the desktop... Or in tiled "Metro mode".  There is literally hundreds of indicators that each browser reveals under the covers.

Comment: @scunliffe Well, if thats the case, then it is indeed hopeless.
Thanks Scunliffe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end goal as determined from comments on the question is to see if there is a way to "hide" a browser's identity from any kind of inspection from JavaScript to aid in creating a custom browser with total anonymity.

I feel that this would be next to impossible based on all of the **hints** that the browser provides that reveals it's true identity.

In the case of Internet Explorer, here is just a sampling of the (readonly) property values that indicate a browser is Internet Explorer

```
//This could be any element
var bStyle = document.body.style;
for(var x in bStyle){
  console.log(x + ':' + bStyle[x]);
}
```

This returns properties like (**ms** is the prefix for Microsoft properties):

```
msBlockProgression: 
msInterpolationMode: 
msBackfaceVisibility:
msPerspective: 
msPerspectiveOrigin: 
msTransformStyle:
msTransform: 
msTransformOrigin: 
msAnimation: 
msAnimationDelay: 
msAnimationDirection: 
msAnimationDuration: 
msAnimationFillMode: 
msAnimationIterationCount: 
msAnimationName: 
msAnimationPlayState: 
msAnimationTimingFunction: 
msFlex: 
msFlexAlign: 
msFlexDirection: 
msFlexFlow: 
msFlexItemAlign: 
msFlexLinePack: 
msFlexNegative: 
msFlexOrder: 
msFlexPack: 
msFlexPositive: 
msFlexPreferredSize: 
msFlexWrap: 
and 50+ more...
```

There's also dozens of IE only APIs that one could check for that would reveal IE.

```
console.log(typeof(window.createPopup));
//>> function in IE, undefined in other browsers

console.log(typeof(document.body.currentStyle));
//>> object in IE, undefined in other browsers
```

Then there's all the IE-only technologies... Active-X, VML, XML Data Islands, VBScript, Behaviors, CSS Expressions, etc.  All provide indicators as to the browser actually being Internet Explorer.

I don't use it personally, but the idea behind the [Tor Browser](https://www.torproject.org/projects/torbrowser.html.en) seems to be the better approach... anonymizing your "tracks" rather that what browser is actually used.