# PNG with black background in iOS 6 Flash IPA

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, png, flash-cs6

with Flash Professional CS6 I'm building an iOS app. Directly in the SWF I have embedded a transparent PNG image (an image with a transparent background). On the Flash IDE stage the image looks perfect, but when I compile and test the IPA on the device:

1. if I test on iPad/iOS 5, the image looks great;
2. if I test on iPhone/iOS 6, the background of the image is black and the image looks stretched and half cut;

What can I do? I tried any kind of PNG (PNG-24, PNG-8, ...) but the issue is always there.

[UPDATE] Same behavior with GIF images too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days, today I solved by just downloading the latest AIR SDK (3.5)!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem looks like the one that is discussed in this thread:
[iOS 6 Safari backgrounds missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520364/ios-6-safari-backgrounds-missing)

Maybe you can apply one of the tips that are mentioned.

Comment: The problem is very much the same but none of the suggested tips works.