# iPad fails to find apple-touch-icon.png for home page bookmark

Tags: ios, ipad, safari, homescreen

I've added 
 `link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png"`  to the main index.php file in the head section.  I've got `apple-touch-icon.png` in the root dir. I've tried 57x57, 72x72 and 114x114 pngs.

When I click the 'Add to Home Screen' button in Safari, the iPad fails to find my .png file.  It shows a black box with a grey outline.  I can't figure out how to get my iPad to use my .png image.

Answer (score 1):

The correct size for iPad is 144px , as 114px is for iPhone retina display.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="apple-touch-icon.png" />
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="apple-touch-icon-retina.png" />
```

Comment: using 144x144 doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Is your PNG transparent?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience with PNG's with iOS, you have to have a transparent background or you will get `a black box with a grey outline`.

Comment: my png is transparent

Comment: I have this: <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://imgur.com/yGTAH9O"/>  in the <head></head> section of index.php and it doesn't work.

Comment: I found this link: http://blog.karlribas.com/2012/05/how-to-create-apple-touch-icon-for-your.html its showing 129X129....

Comment: Was it always a .PNG or did you change the filename

Comment: Here is another S/O article... did you set INTERLACING to False.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12520364/ios-6-safari-backgrounds-missing

Comment: I changed the pic from transparent background to white background and it worked.

Comment: Great! When you can, please put that as an answer so someone else having the same issue can know the resolution.