# How can I scroll an iframe in iOS 4 with 2 fingers?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, iframe

I've found many related questions but none with an answer that explains how to scroll an `iframe` using the 2 finger method in iOS 4.

I am able to scroll a `div` with 2 fingers by setting a `width` and `height` attribute and setting `overflow: scroll;`. Here's a more complete example of this:

```
<div style='width: 280px; height: 200px; overflow: scroll; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;'>
      Just imagine a bunch of content is in here, spanning well over 200px
      worth of height. You can scroll this just fine in iOS 4 by using 2 
      fingers, or in iOS 5 by swiping 1 finger thanks to 
      "-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;".
</div>
```

This same method isn't working on `iframes` on my iPad 1 running iOS 4.3. Here's a complete example that won't scroll with any combination of fingers in iOS 4 (although, of course, the `-webkit-overflow-scrolling` allows it to work on iOS5):

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
    #scroller {
        width: 280px;
        height: 200px;
        overflow: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    }
    #scroller iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="scroller">
    <iframe src="content.html">content.html is a big list of nonsense.</iframe>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

**I must add** that I *can* get 2 finger scrolling to work if I set the `width` and `height` of the `iframe` to actual pixel values, like `height: 1000px;`, but I will never know how tall the iframe's content will be. So, perhaps the real question is how can I convince mobile Safari in iOS 4 that the `iframe` inside of this `div` is indeed larger than 280x200 pixels?

Comment: You can try the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18699378/768685

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple idea posted by rossb @ github.com/fancyapps worked beautifully for both scrolling in iOS 4 (2 fingers) and iOS 5 (1 finger) and solves the "blank content on scroll" issues that iOS 5's iframes seem to be plagued with. Basically, you don't want the iframe to handle any scrolling. Give it a fixed width/height and wrap the scrollable content in your included file in a `div` that *can* be scrolled.

Here's an example:

```
<iframe id="stupid-iframe" width="600" height="200" src="a-file.html"></iframe>
```

a-file.html:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="wrapper" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;">
...all my normal content...
</div>
</body>
</html>
```