# How to view Google drive pdf link in iframe

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, google-drive-api

I need to view pdf file embed with google drive link and view link in iframe.

I have tried following code:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?url=https://library.osu.edu/assets/Documents/SEL/QuickConvertWordPDF.pdf" width="400px" height="300px"  />
```

Advance thanks..

Answer (score 31, accepted):

**Try this..**

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/viewerng/viewer?
url=https://library.osu.edu/assets/Documents/SEL/QuickConvertWordPDF.pdf?
pid=explorer&efh=false&a=v&chrome=false&embedded=true" width="400px" height="300px"  />
```

Comment: Please read How to Answer. Even if the code fixes the problem, you should include some context/explanation surrounding your code to make it more useful to others.

Comment: I agree with @MrMush -- I also agree this accepted solution worked for me. :)

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<iframe src="https://drive.google.com/file/d/(your file id)/preview?usp=embed_googleplus" style="border: 0; top: 0; left: 0; width: 640; height: 700; position: absolute;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Comment: Please read [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Even if the code fixes the problem, you should include some context/explanation surrounding your code to make it more useful to others.

Comment: It's pretty self-explanatory in this situation, look at the answer above mine for example

Comment: Please do creative stuff by answering the questions and not shooting down others on trivial things. At least he is helping by trying to answer the question and its not that big answer that is difficult to understand without proper format @MrMush

Comment: As I commented on both answers, an explanation should be added. This is Stackoverflow policy and there is good reason for it. I don't need to be creative and give a better answer to see that both answers are lacking. What made it work? Clearly it was not obvious to the person that posted the question, non the less, both answers are different and still work. A few words explaining why this way solves the issue will go and long way other than giving a copy paste solution.

Comment: Among other things, this does not solve the person's question: the URL wanting to be embedded is not on a Google Drive, it is hosted at "https://library.osu.edu." Like this person, I'm looking for a solution to view embedded PDFs on pages that are not (or not necessarily) hosted on an actual Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this

```
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/file/d/(your file id)/preview"></iframe>
```

Comment: Among other things, this does not solve the person's question: the URL wanting to be embedded is not on a Google Drive, it is hosted at "https://library.osu.edu." Like this person, I'm looking for a solution to view embedded PDFs on pages that are not (or not necessarily) hosted on an actual Google Drive.