# pdfjs_viewer-rails gem integration - needs reload to show correctly - Amazon s3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, pdf.js

I use the gem pdfjs_viewer-rails for my Rails application and Carrierwave to store my PDF's on Amazon S3.
When i link to a PDF-url i with the mounted route specified by the gem:

```
# routes.rb
mount PdfjsViewer::Rails::Engine => "/pdfjs", as: 'pdfjs'
```

and my view:

```
#_johannes_writing.html.erb
<%= link_to pdfjs.full_path(file: johannes_writing.pdf.url) do %>
<h3>Read <%= johannes_writing.title %></h3>
<% end %>
```

i am redirected to the correct page but the design and function is totally off. 
I have to reload the page to get the proper functionality (se image below )

[BEFORE AND AFTER RELOAD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96iT4.jpg)

#### Now it get strange

If i go back in my browser when i'm on the pdf-view-page without reloading, the css is changed for my #_johannes_writing.html.erb view to the dark-background as the pdf-view.

**If i set my layout to false in my controller, everything is working as it should. The PDF is showing the first time without reload and nothing is changed on a back. So somehow my layout CSS and HTML are interferring with the GEM even though the pdf-view is on its own route?**

What can be the cause of this? 
I tried different opportunities with Iframe integration on its own view (like the gems dokumentation suggests), but nothing helped. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Best Peter

Link to project: http://inger-exner.herokuapp.com/johannes_writings 
(push the word "Læs" under the button to go to PDF-viewer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If any one has the same problem - i found a solution. 
I tried with another gem: [pdfjs_rails](https://github.com/timchunght/pdfjs_rails) 
And followed his instructions. 
So my conclusion is: **try this gem!**

Answer (score 0):

I also tried this gem and also faced with some problem so change it to iframe with Google pdf viewer like in answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/27685952/3884750

Comment: But i wanted to use the PDF.js functionalities (site-view, back and forward) and design.

Comment: Yep, I see but if it doesn't work as expected... you should find another way. I did it on my own. It isn't difficult just a few additional methods... )))