# How to stop automatic download on IE 11 while using iframe

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, iframe, webforms

I have given a source in a Iframe tag, my is issue is that when the page loads on IE the download begins automatically and it generally happens on IE installed on windows 8.

```
<div> <iframe  src="../../Images/Sample.pdf" width="800px" height="800px" ></iframe> </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It's downloaded probably because there is not Adobe Reader plug-in
>   installed. In this case IE (it doesn't matter which version) doesn't
>   know how to render it and it'll simply download file (Chrome, for
>   example, has its own embedded PDF renderer).
>
> That said.  is not best way to display a PDF (do not forget
>   compatibility with mobile browsers, for example Safari). Some browsers
>   will always open that file inside an external application (or in
>   another browser window). Best and most compatible way I found is a
>   little bit tricky but works on all browsers I tried (even pretty
>   outdated):
>
> Keep your  but do not display a PDF inside it, it'll be filled
>   with an HTML page that consists of an  tag. Create an HTML
>   wrapping page for your PDF, it should look like this:
>
> ```
> <html>
> <body>
>     <object data="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf">
>         <embed src="your_url_to_pdf" type="application/pdf" />
>     </object>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```
>
> Of course you still need the appropriate plug-in installed in the
>   browser. Also take a look to this post if you need to support Safari
>   on mobile devices.
>
> 1st. Why nesting  inside ? You'll find answer here on
>   SO. Instead of nested  tag you may even provide a custom
>   message for your users (or a built-in viewer, see next paragraph).
>
> 2nd. Why an HTML page? So you can provide a fallback if PDF viewer
>   isn't supported. Internal viewer, plain HTML error messages/options
>   and so on...
>
> It's tricky to check PDF support so you may provide an alternate
>   viewer for your customers, take a look to PDF.JS project, it's pretty
>   good but rendering quality - for desktop browsers - isn't as good as a
>   native PDF renderer (I didn't see any difference in mobile browsers
>   because of screen size, I suppose).

See also: [HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)