# Does not load PDF file inside IFrame in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I tried to load PDF file in IFrame. it is working with FF and Chrome but does not load in IE. IE asking to save or open to file instead of load in IFrame. I am loading file using javascript.

I am using following code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function setPDF() {
    var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe1');
    iframe.src = "pdffile/sample1.pdf";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<iframe id="iframe1"></iframe>
<input type="button" value="Click" onclick="setPDF();" />
</body>

</html>
```

Please suggest me

Thanks

Comment: We can best help you if you include your relevant code directly into the question. Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn how to improve your question. Then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27779654/edit) your post.

Comment: ok I have add code as you told me. please tell me if you want any more information.

Comment: Please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/12974315/795683

Comment: Yeah I also tried with PDFObject but it did not work as well with IE that's why i replaced with IFrame but still it does not work with IE. This time IE is asking for save and open file instead of display file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe