# Avoid automatic download of pdf on smartphones

Tags: javascript, android, html

I wrote a very simple website for a friend, he needs to show a pdf in a page.
Firstly I've tried with an iframe but I wasn't able to set the height to "100%".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        /*
         * When the iframe is on a different subdomain, uncomment the following line
         * and change "example.com" to your domain.
         */
        // document.domain = "example.com";
        function setIframeHeight(iframe) {
            if (iframe) {
                var iframeWin = iframe.contentWindow || iframe.contentDocument.parentWindow;
                if (iframeWin.document.body) {
                    iframe.height = iframeWin.document.documentElement.scrollHeight || iframeWin.document.body.scrollHeight;
                }
            }
        };

        window.onload = function () {
            setIframeHeight(document.getElementById('mainContent'));
        };
</script>
```

and this is the iframe in the body section

```
<iframe id="mainContent" src="URL_PDF" scrolling=auto frameborder=0  width="100%"></iframe>
```

It works but there is a problem when I try to visit the page with a smartphone (I tested it with android). In particular, the browser attempt to download the file instead of showing it, there is a method to avoid it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML embedded PDF iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution using the library pdf.js