# html pdf viewer: failed to load pdf document

Tags: html, pdf

I want to open a `pdf` file on my `html` document, but the file won't open. Chrome said

> Failed to load PDF document.

Please help.

the `pdf` and the `html` are on the same location on the `localhost` of my computer.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <embed src="1.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<embed src="/1.pdf" width="500" height="375" type='application/pdf'>`??

Comment: Check this link [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2199443/4879022)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Recommended way to embed PDF in HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/recommended-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: Or this: [HTML embedded PDF iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19654577/1207195) for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

below code are working for PDF in chrome browser

```
<object data="Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v2.2.pdf" type="application/pdf">
   <embed src="Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v2.2.pdf" type="application/pdf" />
</object>

<iframe id="iframepdf" src="Certification-Study-Guide-MCD-v2.2.pdf"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

After Struggling with this problem i came to solution, By Referring this Link [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/4281343). Hope this help someone.

**JS:**

```
var file = b64toBlob(pdfBase64, 'application/pdf');//pdfBase64 without content type 
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
```

**HTML**

```
//Added dynamically by Jquery in my case
<iframe src="'+fileURL +'" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```