# Javascript - avoid download file by browser when preview is failing

Tags: javascript, browser, vuejs2, quasar

I am using quasar-framework with vue and I am binding an object propertie to embed a document in a iframe after the user clicks the link which redirects to the path of the file. I don't want to fix the one that is not showing me the file I just want to solve the following:

Is there any way to prevent the browser from downloading by default a selected file to be viewed embedded in an iframe when it can not be displayed?

```
<iframe id="content_iframe" v-bind:src="file.content_url" style="width:100%; background-color: gray" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The file.content_url contains: `"http://10.20.60.30:5010/files/1/content/"`

I need to control this because when I load the new route (then File.vue is loaded) the browser downloads the file with the name 'content' and I want to avoid this and that from that new route the user can download or not the file through a button (which works).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the tag `object` instead of `iframe` for embedding documents. If the browser can't render the document embedded inside `object`, it will not force the download and nothing will be displayed.

```
<object width="400" height="400" data="FILE_URL" type="FILE_CONTENT_TYPE">
    <embed src="FILE_URL" type="FILE_CONTENT_TYPE" />
</object>
```

Source:

- [HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Comment: Beware that this might be a very insecure thing to do. Here’s an example that uses a user-uploaded malicious SVG to exploit an XSS vulnerability:

**exploit.html**: `<object width="400" height="400" data="./evil.svg" type="image/svg+xml"><embed src="./evil.svg" type="image/svg+xml" /></object>`

**evil.svg**: `<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><script type="text/javascript">alert('EXPLOITED')</script></svg>`