# set Src of Iframe of uploaded PDF client side

Tags: java, pdf, iframe, gwt, src

I have uploaded a PDF on server by servlet , get that file on client side. Now I want to set the file to the src of Iframe. I have seen the examples but they are setting the src like  `src='http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf?file=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf`  but I have the file with name like "file12314232343244"
I am setting the src like this

```
HTML pdf = new HTML("<iframe position='absolute'src='http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf?file=http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_tutorial.pdf'  />");
```

what should I do for that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the type parameter:

```
type="application/pdf"
```

as shown https://stackoverflow.com/a/42908837/2979092