# IE 11 pdf download popup instead of preview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, pdf

> **Problem:** I can preview pdf file in all browsers but not in IE 11. IE11 is opening popup like below instead of showing(Preview) in browser:

[image]

I found that if i open pdf useing google docs then it works.But i don't want to use it.

I am returning a partial view as below :

> cs file:

```
return PartialView("~/views/download/_browser-preview.cshtml", new BrowserPreviewViewModel(){ Id = GeneratePreviewToken(document.Id), FileName = document.FileName });
```

> Cshtml file:

```
@model K360.Web.Models.BrowserPreviewViewModel
<div id="browserPreviewWrapper">
    <img id="loader" src="~/content/Images/loader.gif" />
    <iframe style="height: 560px; width: 100%;" class="browser-preview" id="@Model.Id" frameborder="0" src="~/download/browserpreview/@{ WriteLiteral(Model.Id); }#toolbar=0">
        Your browser does not support IFRAME elements.
    </iframe>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.browser-preview').on('load', function () {
        $('#loader').hide();
        $('.browser-preview').css('display', '');
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe help?

Comment: It's a security feature and you cannot by pass it for clients. The clients (users) might have to configure them at their end.

Comment: @mjwills yes i have tried all solution in that article but not working.