# Javascript - View adobe file in HTML (mouse over)

Tags: javascript, html, adobe

I have a list of file which contain **.psd, .ai, .eps,.pdf** in html. I would like to **view the file when mouse over the filename**. Is it possible to that?

Below snippet is example.

```css
.box{
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
}

a:hover + .box,.box:hover{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
This live preview for <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/">Wikipedia</a><div class="box"><iframe src="http://en.wikipedia.org/" width = "500px" height = "500px"></iframe></div> remains open on mouseover.
```

Comment: you can create thumbnails and show these.I don't think there is a way displaying all these formats

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<a href="path to your file" class="preview">Link</a><div class="box"><iframe src="" width = "500px" height = "500px" style="display:none;"></iframe></div>
```

Jquery:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('mouseover','.preview',function(){
var path_source=$(this).attr('href');
$("iframe").attr("src",path_source);
$("iframe").show();

});
 $(document).on('mouseout','.preview',function(){

$("iframe").hide();

});

});
```

Comment: not working.. once mouse over on the link, it download automatically. not preview the file.

Comment: Using an iframe to "render" a PDF will not work on all browsers; it depends on how the browser handles PDF files. Some browsers (such as Firefox and Chrome) have a built-in PDF rendered which allows them to display the PDF inline where as some older browsers (perhaps older versions of IE attempt to download the file instead).

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe