# How to load PDF file inside of iFrame? Working in React

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, iframe

I'm trying to load pdf file inside of iFrame in REACT, the code looks like this:

```
render(){
   return(
      <iframe
          sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-forms"
          title="PortletIFrameWidget"
          src={'.resources/crayola.pdf'}
          ref={(f) => { this.ifr = f }}
      />
   )
}
```

and I'm getting a warning:

> Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type
>   application/pdf: "http://localhost:8080/resources/crayola.pdf"

but when I go to the link: *"http://localhost:8080/resources/crayola.pdf"* I can easily see the content of PDF, so there is the pdf file, the problem is: it's not being uploaded/rendered in iFrame. Why?

THIS WORKS IN MOZILLA FIREFOX, AND IN EDGE, but not in CHROME.

any idea why is this happening? And how to load PDF file in iFrame in REACT

Comment: This has nothing to do with React, check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe

Comment: Try Using Ref in React, and set the src attribute after initial rendering

Answer (score 5):

this has nothing to do with React, the problem obviously is in GOogle-Chrome.
here's the solution I made:

```
<iframe src="./resources/crayola.pdf" title="title">
     Presss me: <a href="./resources/crayola.pdf">Download PDF</a>
</iframe>
```

and the link that helped me:
[PDFobject](https://pdfobject.com/static.html)

Answer (score 4):

Try using an embed tag:

```
<embed src={'.resources/crayola.pdf'} type="application/pdf"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

In React, Use Ref in Functional Component and set after your initial rendering using setAttribute

```js
function App() {
  const refIframe: any = useRef(null);
  
  useEffect(() => {
       refIframe.current.setAttribute(
        'src',
        './resources/crayola.pdf',
    );
  }, []);
  return (
      <iframe
        title="Iframe Doc"
        ref={refIframe}
      />
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why do this over just setting the attribute statically?