# How to render PDF in react?

Tags: reactjs, pdf

I want to render PDF file in my web application. and also want to support scrolling, zooming in, and zooming out.
So I used react-pdf-js, but I can not found how to zooming in/out and scrolling.
I also tried to use mozilla's pdf.js in react, but failed. I need some advice about how to render PDF file in react with scrolling, zooming in and out...Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `<iframe/>` to insert your pdf. It works on most of browsers.

e.g.

```
<iframe src="your path"/>
```

Most of browsers have their own embedded pdf renderer, but some browsers may not support it (e.g. IE), you can find more information in here:[HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Answer (score 1):

```
<ReactPDF
  file={{
    url: 'http://www.example.com/sample.pdf'
  }}
/>
```

use ReactPDF package it will be simple and small

Answer (score 1):

If you use [react-pdf](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf#readme) you can zoom-in or out using the prop `scale` it takes a decimal value separated by `.`

It supports scrolling but you can wrap the document in a div with `max-height` and add `overflow-y: auto` that will add the Y scroll bar.

```
<DocumentWrapper>
  <Document file="file-url">
      <Page pageNumber={this.state.pageNumber} scale={this.state.scale}/>
  </Document>
</DocumentWrapper>
```

Where `DocumentWrapper` is a styled component

```
const DocumentWrapper = styled("div")({
  maxHeight: "600px",
  overflowY: "auto"
});
```

Comment: Where is the `styled` function coming from?

Comment: styled-components, nothing to do with react-pdf, it was my custom implementation
https://styled-components.com/docs/basics#styling-any-component

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://cloudpdf.io/. Which support zooming in and zooming out

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import CloudPdfViewer from "@openbook/cloudpdf-viewer";

export default function App() {
  const viewer = useRef(null);
  useEffect(() => {
    CloudPdfViewer(
      {
        documentId: "eee2079d-b0b6-4267-9812-b6b9eadb9c60",
        darkMode: true
      },
      viewer.current
    ).then((instance) => {});
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <div className="viewer" ref={viewer}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```