# how to fetch a pdf file from a different website and display it in our website without redirecting?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to display a pdf that is available on a different website . how do i do it without redirecting to the website with the file and by using the url

Comment: [Use an iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Answer (score 2):

[Number of solution from Scalified](https://scalified.com/2018/01/16/injecting-pdf-html-page/)

There’re three main options for injecting a PDF into an HTML page:

Using HTML tags iframe, embed and object:

```
<iframe src="https://scalified.com/valid-document-url.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>

<embed src="https://scalified.com/valid-document-url.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></embed>

<object src="https://scalified.com/valid-document-url.pdf" width="100%" height="100%"></object>
```