# How to display a pdf file without it being full screen?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pdf

I would like to display a pdf file on a web app I'm going to make. Thing is, the page is supposed to take up the left half of the screen (not fully) and not be editable, savable or printable (so no tools whatsoever). Is there a way to display it efficiently in a smaller section than it taking up the whole screen (like it does with pdf.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using *iframe* in html to display pdf file in your web app. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)