# read the .pdf in the web page

Tags: php, html, laravel

I read the links of the pdf document in a new page using the code below but I only have the blank page

```
@section('content')
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-plain">
      <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
        <h4 class="card-title">Cotations</h4>
        <p class="card-category">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">
            <a href="D:\Cumputers\Dark Deb\Hunchly-Dark-Web-Setup.pdf" target="_blank">Hunchly-Dark-Web-Setup.pdf</a>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Are you trying to embed a PDF file into your site or you wanted a link on your site that will redirect to that PDF file?

Comment: You can't access your system's folder in your laravel ,unless you have added the filesystem in app/filesystems.php

Comment: You are not “reading” any links here, you have simply set a link that tries to refer to a PDF document in your local file system. Tries to, because this is missing the protocol (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18246053), right now you have just referred to a weirdly named “folder” below the current one. This should probably not be done via the file system in the first place though.

Answer (score 1):

You can check out this post about embedding PDF files on your webpage. [HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

What I've done in the past is used an iframe to achieve this, like so:

```
<iframe style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="My PDF" src="my-pdf.pdf" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="1100" width="850" ></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use object tag

```html
@section('content')
<div class="content">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="card card-plain">
      <div class="card-header card-header-primary">
        <h4 class="card-title">Cotations</h4>
        <p class="card-category">lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
        </p>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row">

          <div class="col-md-12">
           
           <!-- pdf here -->
           <object width="400" height="400" data="http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/testpages/test.pdf">
</object>

          <!-- pdf here -->
          <!-- or iframe -->
          <iframe src="http://plugindoc.mozdev.org/testpages/test.pdf" width="400" height="400" frameborder="0"></iframe>
            
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Otavio and @jass. I tried it with ifram and it work.

```
<iframe style="border:none" src="{{URL::asset('/material/docs/laravel-PDF/laravel.pdf')}}"  scrolling="auto" height="700" class="col-md-10"></iframe>
```

I wanted to specify also that we had to use the link the way laravel does it