# Django display a pdf in an iframe

Tags: django, python-3.x, templates, iframe, django-2.1

Currently I am Working on a workflow where on the left side are input fields and on the right half is a scalable pdf.

But actually I am not able to show a PDF in an iframe.

I am using django 2.1.1(python 3.7.2) on windows.
Is there any solution to display a pdf in an iframe?

I hope you have some ideas..i looked up many sides an tried different solution but actually the pdf document is not shown..
Hope to hear from you soon!

Kind regards

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML embedded PDF iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19654577/html-embedded-pdf-iframe)

Comment: Sorry, but this is not a duplicate of this. Actually the recommendation did not help.

Comment: To be honest, it does not have to be an iframe, it could be everything. But at the moment I am not able to display a pdf document in the browser width django. Is there no solution for this problem?

Comment: It does not work, I tested it with pdf.js and the document is not loading, I got no error in the console, the document is really not loading.
So Is there any recommendation which is helpful? I can not believe that I am the only one which is struggling with a Pdf viewer in django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have experienced a similar setting where I wanted to render a PDF in a webpage.
For that, I did the following :
Wrote a view method (in `views.py`) that renders the pdf's name. Indicated in the `urls.py` the path used for the view method. Next, in the HTML file, I use the following line of code :

```
<iframe id="iframe_pdf" src="{{ doc_file.url }}" 
      style="width:800px; height:800px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

The `{{ doc_file.url }}` is the data obtained from the View method, it returns the PDF file location as a string. In my case, the pdfs were stored in the `MEDIA_ROOT` directory set in `settings.py`.