# HTML embed tag problem - green loading bar

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I would like to embed an PDF preview in my web site. With the embed tag it works fine on modern browsers, but on older versions the following shows up:

[image]

Does someone know how to solve it without using any external JS library?

The data that I would like to preview is a base64 encoded pdf.

```
<embed src="data:application/pdf;base64,[:base64-encoded-pdf:]" width="100%" height="640px">
```

Comment: Does this solution (or any of the other solutions on the page) help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19654875

Comment: tried using iframes?

Comment: @Steve it doesn't

Comment: I will try with an iframe, but the data is bas64 encoded not na url could that be a problem

Answer (score 0):

On older browsers, it may be an issue to use Data URIs, so try uploading your pdf to a website and embedding it into an iframe.

```
<iframe src='https://www.example.com/example.pdf' width="100%" height="640px">
Something went wrong :(
</iframe>
```

Comment: Then try turning the [data URI into a blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12168909/blob-from-dataurl)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!-- initially load about:blank for MSIE -->
<iframe id="pdf" src="about:blank" height="100%" width="100%"></iframe>
```

```js
var pdf_data_uri="data:application/pdf;base64," + PDF_DATA;
document.getElementById("pdf").setAttribute('src', pdf_data_uri);
```