# Scrolling with single finger gesture for <object> element- IPAD not working

Tags: html, css, ipad, safari, embed

I have an weird requirement. I want to scroll the embedded pdf within `<object> or <embed>` element with one finger. As of now I am able to scroll the embedded content with two fingers.

```
Tried following elements
1. <object>
2. <embed>
```

Read many articles and got to know that two fingers scroll gesture is standard practice by Apple. Still want to try my luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just a faint idea: does `overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` on the Container solve the issue?

Comment: Have you looked at this? https://css3wizardry.com/tag/one-finger-scrolling/

Comment: @SamMearns : Didnt worked for Embed PDF within an <object> Element or <embed> element. Any luck or dummy example you can provide with embeded pdf. 

Thanks in advance

Comment: @LarsBeck: Hey it worked for me. Thank you so much buddy.

Though -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; is deprecated but for me it worked. Thank you so much.

Comment: @Krishna9960 Nice to hear this, since it solved the issue I’d post this as an answer then (-:

Comment: hehe sure :) Go ahead

Comment: @Krishna9960 So I did

Answer (score 2):

Although I’ve no explanation why Mobile Safari explicitly needs this, adding `overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` to the container makes the PDF scrollable.

Answer (score 1):

`overflow: auto; -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;` is a workaround for `<iframe>` elements. It doesn't work for the `<object>` elements, which is a more natural way to embed a pdf.